# How to delete a document in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to create a delete method in order to delete a document that has the key:"name" and the value:"Rhonda". Whenever I execute my current code, I get an AttributeError saying:"'AnimalShelter' object has no attribute 'delete'". How do I get the method to return the deleted document's JSON contents? Here is my code:

testing_script.ipynb

```
from animal_shelter import AnimalShelter
# now need to create the object from the class
shelter = AnimalShelter("aacuser","Superman")
data = {"age_upon_outcome":"2 years","animal_type":"Dog","breed":"Dachshund","color":"Black and tan","name":"Rhonda","outcome_subtype":"Partner","outcome_type":"Adopt","sex_upon_outcome":"Female"}
new_values = {"$set": {"age_upon_outcome":"3 years"}}

# if shelter.create(data):
#    print("Animal added")
# else:
#     print("Failed to add animal")

# Calls the read function
# shelter.read(data)

# Calls the update function
# shelter.update(data, new_values)

# Calls the delete function
shelter.delete(data)
```

output

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-60b1d887dfb8> in <module>
 17 
 18 # Calls the delete function
---> 19 shelter.delete(data)
 20 

AttributeError: 'AnimalShelter' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

animal_shelter.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
""" CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

def __init__(self,username,password):
    # Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to 
    # access the MongoDB databases and collections. 
    # init to connect to mongodb without authentication
    self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:55996')
    # init connect to mongodb with authentication
    # self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:55996/?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=AAC'%(username, password))
    self.database = self.client['AAC']

# Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
def create(self, data):
    if data is not None:
        self.database.animals.insert(data)  # data should be dictionary  
        return True # Tells whether the create function ran successfully
    else:
        raise Exception("Nothing to save ...")

# Create method to implement the R in CRUD.     
def read(self, data):
    return self.database.animals.find_one(data) #returns only one

# Update method to implement the U in CRUD.
def update(self, data, new_values):
    if self.database.animals.count(data):
        self.database.animals.update(data, new_values)
        return self.database.animals.find({"age_upon_outcome":"3 years"})
    else:
        raise Exception("Nothing to update ...") 
        
# Delete method to implement the D in CRUD
def delete(self, data)
    result = self.database.animals.find_one_and_delete(data)
    # print the _id key only if the result is not None
    if("_id" in result):
        print("find_one_and_delete ID:",result["_id"])
    else:
        print("Nothing to delete")
```

Comment: You're missing a `:` after defining the `delete` method.

Comment: @Adid also he is not providing intendation for all function in class, which caused the Attribute Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that functions that you are defining are outside the class. You have to put indentation on functions in class `AnimalShelter`

Also as pointed out in comment you are missing : in delete

Updated animal_sheltor.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
""" CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init__(self,username,password):
    # Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to 
    # access the MongoDB databases and collections. 
    # init to connect to mongodb without authentication
        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:55996')
    # init connect to mongodb with authentication
    # self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:55996/?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=AAC'%(username, password))
        self.database = self.client['AAC']

# Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            self.database.animals.insert(data)  # data should be dictionary  
            return True # Tells whether the create function ran successfully
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save ...")

# Create method to implement the R in CRUD.     
    def read(self, data):
        return self.database.animals.find_one(data) #returns only one

# Update method to implement the U in CRUD.
    def update(self, data, new_values):
        if self.database.animals.count(data):
            self.database.animals.update(data, new_values)
            return self.database.animals.find({"age_upon_outcome":"3 years"})
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to update ...") 
        
# Delete method to implement the D in CRUD
    def delete(self, data):
        result = self.database.animals.find_one_and_delete(data)
    # print the _id key only if the result is not None
        if("_id" in result):
            print("find_one_and_delete ID:",result["_id"])
        else:
            print("Nothing to delete")
```